# creating a network from a list in python3

Tags: python-3.x

So, I'm stuck with this problem.

I am given a list of users who are friends

For example: the list appears so that

```
0 1,
1 2,
1 8,
2 3
```

and should return

```
[(0,[1]), (1,[0,2,8]), (2,[1,3]), (3,[2]), (8,[1])]
```

This is what I have so far:

```py
network = []

for i in lines[1: (len(lines))]:
    network.append(i.split(" "))

network.sort()
secondary = [[]] * (len(lines)//2) #empty lists
for j in network:
    for k in secondary:
    #to make a new list for each user
        secondary[k].append(network[j][0])
```

But it says:

```py
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

I've tried experimenting and I'm still not sure why

Comment: Please post the full error message, which would include where the error is occurring. Also, it is not clear what `network` and `lines` are

Comment: In need of the full Traceback